# Antlr4 build task for C# target with Java portable runtime

Tags: java, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 for C# target.

As far as I unterstand from Antlr4BuildTasks.net40.dll, the registry will be searched to decide if Java runtime is installed on the machine. But for me it is not possible to install Java runtime on the build machine, so I need to use a portable Java runtime. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the path in the command line for `msbuild.exe`.

```
"/p:Antlr4JavaExecutable=PATH_TO_JAVA"
```

Here, `PATH_TO_JAVA` is the path to the Java executable you want to use, typically with the form **C:\Path\To\java.exe** (on Windows machines).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I am trying this one now.

msbuild.exe AntlrParser.csproj /p:Antlr4JavaExecutable="T:\java32\Java\bin"

But I am getting now another error: Antlr4.targets: error AC1000: Unknown build error: Access denied

As path to java, i gave it where the Java.exe from JPortable runtime is

Comment: @HüseyinGülle It needs to be the path to the Java executable itself, not the directory where the executable is located.

Comment: @ Sam Harwell Thanks a lot. That worked very well! One more question. Can I define this path directly in csproj so that I don't have to give it in the command line for msbuild? If possible, how?

Comment: @ Sam Harwell Ok, meanwhile, I managed to integrate setting this msbuild property in the csproj. Thanks a lot again.